# How do you count different values inside of a field of rastercells (1x1km) in QGIS?

Tags: qgis

A friend and I need to create a Geodiversity Index for a German Bundesland(/State). Right now were stuck on a Geology-Map. Our idea would be to divide the whole state into 1x1km Raster-Cells and count, how many Types of Geology are contained within a Cell. We'd do this for every Cell and create an Index based on the Diversity of Values. Heres the Problem:

We can't find a Tool, that does that for us (were both very new to QGIS).
Is there a Tool, that automatically determines the Values inside every raster cell and if it exists, whats the Name of it?

Answer (score 0):

I could be misunderstanding you but a raster can only have one value in each cell, unless you have more than one band.

You can create a polygon layer with rectangles of size 1*1 km using [Create Grid](https://docs.qgis.org/3.34/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorcreation.html#qgiscreategrid), set the extent to that of your raster layer.

Then use [Zonal Statistics](https://docs.qgis.org/3.34/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/rasteranalysis.html#qgiszonalstatisticsfb) with your Grid polygons and your raster layer as inputs, with statistics to calculate **Variety**. Output will be a new grid layer with the count of unique raster values inside the polygon.

(I dont know if it is a bug or a problem with my data but I had to select all **Statistics to calculate**, to get Variety to work, otherwise all rows were 0)

[image]